# Help to solve exponential equation over positive integers

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the equation

$\frac{4}{9} = \big( \frac{1}{3} \big) ^n + \big( \frac{1}{3} \big) ^m $

with $n$ and $m$ both positive integers.

I type into Mathematica the following

In:= Solve[4/9 == 1/3^m + 1/3^n && m > 0 && n > 0, n, Integers]

which spits out "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

The solution to the problem is $n=1\:\&\:m=2$ or $n=2\:\&\:m=1$. How can I change my input to have Mathematica come up with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to ask for an answer using `FindInstance`

```
FindInstance[4/9 == (1/3)^m + (1/3)^n && m > 0 && n > 0, {n, m}]
```

> ```
> {{n -> 2, m -> 1}}
> ```

As Nasser points out in the comment, you can replace the requirements that `m>0` and `n>0` by insisting that `n` and `m` are integers:

```
FindInstance[(4/9) == (1/3)^n + (1/3)^m, {n, m}, Integers]
```

Both give the same answer.

Comment: fyi, `FindInstance[(4/9) == (1/3)^n + (1/3)^m, {n, m}, Integers]` also.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea that function existed. Mathematica is huge.

Comment: `Solve`, `FindInstance`, and `Reduce` are all devoted to this kind of thing. I always try out all three -- in this case, `FindInstance` was the most useful.